# how to populate data model from json response and add to list C#

Tags: c#, json, database, httpclient

I am trying to get some json data from a MySql database hosted on a web server and populate a data model which I want to use to display my database entries in a list. Currently I have been able to deserialize the data on find how many entries are in the table but I am getting stuck on how to populate the data model which I can add to my list.

My code is

```
public async Task<List<JobItem>> RefreshJobsAsync()
{
    JobItems = new List<JobItem>();
    var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.RestUrl, Constants.JobsUrl));
    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var job = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);

            Debug.WriteLine("MySql Table has " + job.jobs.records.Count + " jobs entries"); // Output in console is [0:] MySql Table has 3 jobs entries
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"              ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    return JobItems;
}
```

I used json2Sharp.com to generate these classes

```
public class Jobs
{
    public List<string> columns { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> records { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Jobs jobs { get; set; }
}
```

My data model that I want to populate is

```
public class JobItem
{
    public string job_id { get; set; }
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string start_date { get; set; }
    public string start_time { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string qualification { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string minimum_experience { get; set; }
    public string position_filled { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_posted { get; set; }
}
```

and finally the json response is

```
{
  "jobs": {
    "columns": [
      "job_id",
      "user_id",
      "start_date",
      "start_time",
      "description",
      "qualification",
  "address",
  "minimum_experience",
  "position_filled",
  "date_posted"
],
"records": [
  [
    1,
    0,
    "0000-00-00",
    "00:00:00",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "0",
    "2017-09-25 17:46:08"
  ],
  [
    4,
    0,
    "0000-00-00",
    "00:00:00",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "0",
    "2017-09-25 17:46:08"
  ],
  [
    5,
    0,
    "0000-00-00",
    "00:00:00",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "0",
    "2017-09-25 17:46:08"
   ]
   ]
 }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `List<List<object>>` instead of the type you want to deserialize to (`JobItem`)? Also, while that's valid JSON, you should always use the property name

Comment: You should deserialize the json object to a c# poco and then work with it

Comment: @rmjoia `JsonConvert` **is** part of NewtonSoft.Json

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto you're right, I didn't fully read the code. yet, should be deserialized I will remove the reference from my comment, thanks